# Weird behavior of phototransistor

Tags: led, phototransistor, uv

Tonight I debugged a weird issue with a simple IR LED/phototransistor circuit that I was meaning to integrate in a RPM sensor.

With the IR LED pointed towards the phototransistor, with a gap of 1-2cm between the two, I would cover either of them with my fingers and I would see no change on the scope (almost zero voltage across the phototransistor, meaning it was seeing the LED).

A piece of metal or plastic would block the light, also my fingers if I put on electrical tape on the fingertips. But not my bare fingers. I wrote that off to subsurface scattering.

However, I would also not see the voltage rise if I used a piece of cardboard, either black or white, which is very weird. Any idea what would be the cause?

Comment: I remember black paint being white for Infrared reflection but a Sharpy on metal made perfect black stripe for power meter reading. was all ambient blocked? THere's a lot more scattering reflection at UV.  I suspect you meant IR which transmits thru fingers. Normally you would never use UV unless verifying authenticity of money and antibacterial use

Comment: what can you shine easier through your hand: a blue light or a red light?

Comment: It is indeed IR. I was tired and mixed them up. Sorry!

Answer (score -2):

Try this circuit, to evaluate the small-signal sensitivity

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDCT4m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>